# Handling hyperlink right clicks on a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am trying to detect right clicks on hyperlinks in a JTextPane in my program.  There really is nothing on the issue online.  Can someone help me?

```
public class rchltest extends Applet {

    public void init() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);

        JEditorPane gentextp = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gentextp);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        gentextp.setContentType("text/html");
        gentextp.setEditable(false);
        gentextp.addHyperlinkListener(new texthll());
        gentextp.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 500, 400 ) );
        gentextp.setText("Here is a <a href='http://A'>hyperlink</a>");

        this.add( panel );

    }
}

class texthll implements HyperlinkListener  {

        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            JEditorPane pane = (JEditorPane)event.getSource();

            URL url = event.getURL();

                // Show the new page in the editor pane.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a traditional mouse listener. HyperlinkListener forwards only mouse move and left-clicks.

Here is a small demo code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;

public class TestHyperlinks {

    private final class HyperlinkMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                Element h = getHyperlinkElement(e);
                if (h != null) {
                    Object attribute = h.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A);
                    if (attribute instanceof AttributeSet) {
                        AttributeSet set = (AttributeSet) attribute;
                        String href = (String) set.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
                        if (href != null) {
                            try {
                                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(href));
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Element getHyperlinkElement(MouseEvent event) {
            JEditorPane editor = (JEditorPane) event.getSource();
            int pos = editor.getUI().viewToModel(editor, event.getPoint());
            if (pos >= 0 && editor.getDocument() instanceof HTMLDocument) {
                HTMLDocument hdoc = (HTMLDocument) editor.getDocument();
                Element elem = hdoc.getCharacterElement(pos);
                if (elem.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A) != null) {
                    return elem;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);

        JEditorPane gentextp = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gentextp);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        gentextp.setContentType("text/html");
        gentextp.setEditable(false);
        gentextp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        gentextp.addMouseListener(new HyperlinkMouseListener());
        gentextp.setText("Some text containing an hyperlink: <a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\">a link to stackoverflow</a> and some more text not in an hyperlink");

        JFrame f = new JFrame(TestHyperlinks.class.getSimpleName());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(f.getWidth() + 100, f.getHeight() + 100);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestHyperlinks().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I think your solution is great!  Tyvm  -Roland

Answer (score 3):

Add usual `MouseListener` and listen right click. On click use `viewToModel()` method of the `JEditorPane` to get offset in the Document. Then check whether use `getCharacterElement()` method of `StyledDocument` to get leaf Element. Then check whether the leaf is hyperlink or not.

Or you can use this http://java-sl.com/tip_links_in_editable.html to implement your own `LinkController`

Answer (score 0):

A single class (`HyperTextPane`) based on @GuillaumePolet's code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main {

    static void showUI() {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            () -> {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                HyperTextPane label = new HyperTextPane("<html>Visit new: <a href=\"http://www.google.pl\">google</a><br>" +
                        "Visit <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow</a>" +
                        "</html>");
                label.setHyperlinkClickListener(
                        (e,href,button) -> {
                            if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                                HyperTextPane.openHyperlink(href);
                            } else if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                                label.showHyperlinkCopyMenu(e,href);
                            }
                });
                frame.add(label);
                frame.setSize(800,600);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
    );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    showUI();
    }
}

class HyperTextPane extends JTextPane {
    HyperlinkClickListener hyperlinkClickListener;

    public HyperTextPane(String htmlText) {
    setContentType("text/html");
    setEditable(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Element h = getHyperlinkElement(e);
            if (h != null) {
                Object attribute = h.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A);
                if (attribute instanceof AttributeSet) {
                    AttributeSet set = (AttributeSet) attribute;
                    String href = (String) set.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
                    if (href != null) {
                        hyperlinkClickListener.onHyperlinkClicked(h, href, e.getButton());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    setText(htmlText);
    }
    public void setHyperlinkClickListener(HyperlinkClickListener hyperlinkClickListener) {
    this.hyperlinkClickListener = hyperlinkClickListener;
    }
    private Element getHyperlinkElement(MouseEvent event) {
    JEditorPane editor = (JEditorPane) event.getSource();
    int pos = editor.getUI().viewToModel(editor, event.getPoint());
    if (pos >= 0 && editor.getDocument() instanceof HTMLDocument) {
        HTMLDocument hdoc = (HTMLDocument) editor.getDocument();
        Element elem = hdoc.getCharacterElement(pos);
        if (elem.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A) != null) {
            return elem;
        }
    }
    return null;
    }
    public static boolean openHyperlink(String href) {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(href));
        return true;
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
    }
    public void showHyperlinkCopyMenu(Element elem, String href) {
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
    popup.add("Copy URL");
    ((JMenuItem)popup.getComponent(0)).addActionListener(e -> {
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(href);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);            }
    );
    try {
        Rectangle rec = modelToView(elem.getStartOffset());
        popup.show(this, rec.x, rec.y+rec.height);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public interface HyperlinkClickListener {
    void onHyperlinkClicked(Element element, String href, int mouseButton);
    }
}
```

This example also shows opening a hyperlink in the default browser, and copying the hyperlink address to the clipboard.