# A Java context menu triggered by a hyperlink

Tags: java, swing, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling hyperlink right clicks on a JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932089/handling-hyperlink-right-clicks-on-a-jtextpane)

This may be a simple question but I can't seem to get this done right!  How can I trigger a contextual pop up menu when the hyperlink is clicked?

```
public class rchltest extends Applet {

    public void init() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);

        JEditorPane gentextp = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gentextp);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        gentextp.setContentType("text/html");
        gentextp.setEditable(false);
        gentextp.addHyperlinkListener(new texthll());
        gentextp.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 500, 400 ) );
        gentextp.setText("Here is a <a href='http://A'>hyperlink</a>");

        this.add( panel );

    }
}

class texthll implements HyperlinkListener  {

        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            JEditorPane pane = (JEditorPane)event.getSource();

            URL url = event.getURL();

                // Show the new page in the editor pane.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this different from your last question ... exact same code without any traces of taking up the advice given there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12932089/203657

Comment: I will need to work on that in the morning.  Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @Confident Takind the code I provided you in my answer to your previous question, all you have to do is create a JPopupMenu upon the right-click event and make it visible: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup

Comment: -1 in addition to the vote to close as duplicate: you don't really expect anybody to answer the exact same question again within minutes without you showing _any_ effort? If you can wait until the morning, fine with me ;-) If you can't wait pay someone to do _your_ work for you.